# Saving citizens in the quest: The Widow's Wrath

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In the quest "The Widow's Wrath" in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* I accidentally told the widow that I would kill all of the Canneroc citizens. I don't want to do this. I tried attacking her and turning the safety mode off but it wouldn't let me. When I talk to her again she just says something about how we are allies for the moment.

Is there any way I can decide not to kill the citizens and instead kill her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. You can either load a previously saved game or just play along and kill the citizens. It will only affect your fate a little.